# Why does my event run twice?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a button

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  onclick="Button1_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

and my event is

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Document_RecordConnectionString1").ToString())
        con.Open()
        Dim del As New SqlCommand(" delete from TableA where RefNo = '" & Request.QueryString("RefNo") & "'", con)
        del.ExecuteNonQuery()
        For i As Integer = 0 To displayCBL.Items.Count - 1

            If displayCBL.Items(i).Selected Then
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into TableA (RefNo,Text,InsertDate) values('" & Request.QueryString("RefNo") & "','" & displayCBL.Items(i).Value & "',getdate())", con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End If
        Next
        con.Close()
End Sub
```

I notice my sub routine run twice hence insert data twice(Both debugger and SQL Server profiler confirm this). Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simple. The code above call the event TWICE. By having both `onclick="Button1_Click"`or `Handles Button1.Click` are mistakes. Choose either one is sufficient.

You may read more on :

[OnClick and Handles Caution: Events Firing Twice](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/19/onclick-and-handles-caution.aspx)

[ASP.Net OnClick vs Function() Handles buttonName.Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088840/asp-net-onclick-vs-function-handles-buttonname-click)

Comment: Wonder why there are two ways of associating the button and the OnClick function?